# Flask can't find static files with webpack

Tags: javascript, python, flask, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I'm currently creating a project involving flask and webpack. Currently the flask server is able to find the revelant template, but is not able to find the relevant JavaScript.

I have a webpack config for creating the HTML file using the webpack html plugin like so:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {app: './src/index.js', print: './src/print.js'},
    output: {filename: '[name].bundle.js', path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')},
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template:"./src/index.html"}), new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'])],
};
```

This uses a template called index.html in the src directory which contains the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hellow World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>It Works</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Which should be bundled by webpack with the following javascript, 
index.js:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import printMe from './print.js';

function component() {
    let element = document.createElement('div');
    let btn = document.createElement('button');

    // lodash now imported
    element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ');

    // new button
    btn.innerHTML = 'Click me and check the console!';
    btn.onclick = printMe;

    element.appendChild(btn);

    return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

and print.js:

```
export default function printMe() {
  console.log('I get called from print.js!');
}
```

The app.py looks like the following:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="dist/", static_folder="dist/")


@app.route("/")
def index():
    """
    renders basic index page
    :return: template
    """
    return render_template("index.html")


# app entry point
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

After running a build, a template is produced in the dist folder with the following content in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hellow World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>It Works</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="print.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I can't workout how it is able to find the template but not able to find the relevant JavaScript.

Comment: What else do you have in the `dist` folder?

Comment: print.bundle.js and app.bundle.js

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct URL for `app.bundle.js` as per your configuration is `/dist/app.bundle.js`

If you want to serve static files from a different folder, you have to set the `static_url_path` parameter, in this case to `""`:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="dist", static_folder="dist", static_url_path="")
```

---

Reference: https://vilimpoc.org/blog/2012/11/21/serving-static-files-from-root-and-not-static-using-flask/

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @Warmley You're welcome :)